# Program that will compute the maximum and the minimum of a sequence of integers

Tags: java

In my code i am trying to find from a sequence of numbers input by the user, the average of the sequence, the max number and the min number. My problem is that i dont know how i will make my code, so when the user types 0 or a negative integer to stop and make the calculations.

```
public class Sequence2
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        double sum = 0;
        double avg = 0;
        int n;

        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of positive integers, which will end with either 0 or a negative integer. ");
        int max = keyb.nextInt();
        int min = keyb.nextInt();
        while (keyb.hasNextInt())
        {
            n = keyb.nextInt();
            if (n > max)
            {
                max = n;
            }
            if (n < min)
            {
                min = n;
            }
            count++;
            sum += n;
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum value is: " + max);
        System.out.println("The minimum value is: " + min);
        avg = sum / count;
        System.out.println("Average = " + avg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and tell us where exactly in your code the problem lies?

Comment: You can break out of the loop with `break` (in case `n <= 0`).

Comment: Change the 2 lines as follows: `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` and `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot guys! you helped me a ton!!!

Answer (score 1):

The key points to solving this problem are to maintain state for the minimum and maximum values seen which is defined *outside* the loop.  In particular, the minimum value should be seeded with the *maximum* possible integer value, and the maximum value can be seeded with zero.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int minimum = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int maximum = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        int num = keyb.nextInt();
        if (num <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Exiting input loop.");
            break;
        }

        if (num < minimum) {
            minimum = num;
        }
        if (num > maximum) {
            maximum = num;
        }
        total += num;
        ++counter;
    }

System.out.println("minimum: " + minimum);
System.out.println("maximum: " + maximum);
System.out.println("average: " + (total / counter));
```

I omitted a few things, such as handling the possibility that the user does not enter a valid integer into the scanner.  Also, I assume that the user would always enter at least one valid integer.  If not, we would have to handle the average arithmetic at the end to avoid a divide by zero.

Comment: From the question it looks like the input loop should terminate when `num <= 0` instead of `num < 0`

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea if you want to make it more Java-8-esque.

1. First, you collect all integers from the user in a `List<Integer>`
2. Then you compute the `IntSummaryStatistics` and extract the min, max and average:

```
result = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summarizingInt(Integer::intValue));

min = result.getMin();
max = result.getMax();
average = result.getAverage();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, however you don't need to predeclare the variable `avg` at the top of your code since that is just calculated at the end.

For the loop exit condition use an if statement to break the while loop when the input is less than or equal to zero:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sequence2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0, overallMax = 0, overallMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter a sequence of positive integers, which will end with either 0 or a negative integer. ");

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int num = scanner.nextInt();
                if (num <= 0) {
                    scanner.close();
                    break;
                }
                overallMax = Math.max(overallMax, num);
                overallMin = Math.min(overallMin, num);
                count++;
                sum += num;
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid Input. Enter a integer!");
                scanner.next();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The maximum value is: " + overallMax);
        System.out.println("The minimum value is: " + overallMin);
        double avg = sum / count;
        System.out.println("Average: " + avg);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
Enter a sequence of positive integers, which will end with either 0 or a negative integer.
4
a
ERROR: Invalid Input. Enter a integer!
2
6
-1
The maximum value is: 6
The minimum value is: 2
Average: 4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. If we want to do this with minimal changes to your existing code, I would say that the simplest option is to add a boolean flag indicating whether or not to continue looping:

Before your while loop

```
boolean userWantsToQuit = false;
```

This should be your loop condition:

```
while (keyb.hasNextInt() && !userWantsToQuit)
```

Then in your while loop, you'll want to add this if statement BEFORE the other if statements

```
if(n<=0){userWantsToQuit=true}
```

You'll also probably want to switch the other if statements to be else if statements attached to this conditional - otherwise you will always get 0 or the negative number that you used to quit as the lowest number entered.

You can also use a break statement instead of a boolean flag - That is a matter of personal preference. I was always taught to avoid break statements for some reason, so I usually use flags, but either is a valid approach.

This is not the most idiomatic solution, but it is the one that most similarly follows the pattern you already have set up.